# SQL Add Sum Row for Week and At the End Add the Grand Total

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table which has Columns Like numberofCalls, Date, CallsNotRecieved etc.

I am in need of a way to get this records for a month but at the end of each Saturday i have to Show the week total and after all i have to show the Grand Total for the Month.

Is it posible in SQL server? Any Help?

Comment: What should be done with partial weeks at the start/end of the month?

Comment: yes have to total the partial weeks also. in Start of month give total uptill saturday and at the end give total for the remaining days. let say till Thursday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give us more information on data structure. Assuming that your `[Date]` column is of type `datetime`, and that you want all your date/week total/month total in one column:

```
set datefirst 7

select 
    case 
        when grouping(cast(datepart(week, [Date]) as varchar(255)))=1 then '<monthtotal>'       
        when grouping(cast([Date] as date))=1 then '<weektotal>'        
        else cast(cast([Date] as date) as varchar(255))
    end as Period
    ,CallsNotRecieved = sum(CallsNotRecieved)
    ,NumberOfCalls = sum(numberofCalls)
from <yourtable>
group by 
    grouping sets(  
    (cast(datepart(month, [Date]) as varchar(255)), cast(datepart(week, [Date]) as varchar(255)),cast([Date] as date)),
    (cast(datepart(month, [Date]) as varchar(255)), cast(datepart(week, [Date]) as varchar(255))),
    (cast(datepart(month, [Date]) as varchar(255)))
    )
```

You can figure out how to do this without `set datefirst`, insert week/month number instead of weektotal and monthtotal, and also make sure that data set is ordered by using `order by grouping()`, and `order by [Period]`

Edit:
In sql server 2005, as there's no `grouping sets`, one would have to use `WITH ROLLUP` (or worse - `WITH CUBE`) clause, and then filter out unneeded grouping combinations with `grouping(<column_name>)=1`

Comment: @frikozoid it is working fine in SQL server 2008 and Sql server2012 but on server there is sql server 2005 installed. How can we get this to work for Sql server 2005. Waiting anxiosly for your reply.

Comment: @user1796443 As grouping sets were introduced in 2008 (btw you tagged your question with sql-server-2008), you can't use GROUPING SETS, obviously. See the edit.